# Spawning after time passed in C

Tags: c, spawn

I'm making simple game and trying to make char spawn after 5 sec from the start of the game. This is part of my code and I not sure if I have to use time.h or loop function or something. Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you

```
char * image =
/**/    "H   H"
/**/    "H   H"
/**/    "HHHHH"
/**/    "H   H"
/**/    "H   H";

#define HERO_WIDTH (5)
#define HERO_HEIGHT (5)

void setup_hero( void ) {
    // Set up the hero at the centre of the screen.
    int hero_x = ( screen_width() - HERO_WIDTH ) / 2;
    int hero_y = ( screen_height() - HERO_HEIGHT ) / 2;
    hero = sprite_create( hero_x, hero_y, HERO_WIDTH, HERO_HEIGHT, image );

   wait(5); // not working
   sprite_draw(image);  
   show_screen();
}
```

Comment: The syscall is to pause for x seconds is usually called `sleep`, not `wait`.

Comment: So will sleep function work while the game is still running, like while your playing the char is spawned?

Comment: You should get warnings from your compiler. Either that `wait` is undeclared or that it doesn't take an `int`. If you're not getting them, tweak your build system.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep is a POSIX system function for descheduling your process. You call it, your process goes off of the CPU for x seconds, and only then gets run again.

Comment: Reading the documentation definitely helps here, at least to learn that `wait()` obviously does something else then waiting for a time specified on its call.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, games are event-oriented. They have a main loop that pretty much does nothing but poll the user input, update a timer, and update/render all the entities in the scene.

The timer updated by the main loop keeps track of the number of milliseconds passed since the last iteration of the loop, and is often called the 'delta' time. Delta time is extremely useful for scaling the speed of animation and sound, because the amount of time it takes for the main loop to complete varies depending on a large number of factors.

One way to accomplish what you're trying to do give your entity a counter set to 0 when it's first spawned. Every time the entity is updated, add the delta time to the counter. When the counter is greater than or equal to 5000ms, then 5 seconds have passed.

The best way to implement delta time in C is to use the `clock` function in `<time.h>`. It returns the number of cpu cycles that have passed since the program was started. Dividing this value by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000` will give you the number of milliseconds that have passed. subtract the time for the last iteration from the current time to get the delta time.

see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm